# Sorting using Bucket Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What exactly defines the size of bucket while sorting? Like in counting the size 
will be from 0 to max and in radix the bucket size is 0-9.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bucket+sort

Comment: The question looks pretty vague. IMO, counting sort is based on counting the number of occurrences of each element while radix sort is a different sorting algo altogether.

Comment: yeah I have just used others sorting algorithms as example. I just want to know how we define the size of bucket in bucket sort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of "buckets" in Bucket Sort corresponds to and depends on the **range of possible values that are to be sorted**. For example, if I am considering the following values:

```
1, 4, 10000, 5, 12
```

The range of the values I am sorting  is 9999.

```
range = (highest value) - (lowest value) = 10000 - 1 = 9999 buckets
```

This means that I will need 9999 buckets to sort these values as efficiently as possible. This is because Bucket Sort is NOT a comparison sort. This means that values are not compared to each other to determine their order. They are simply placed in buckets that represent their values. Bucket Sort is hailed to be *O(n)* because of this, but it actually tends to be much less efficient due to the amount of buckets needed to be created.

With the previous example we only were sorting 5 values, but needed to create upwards of 10,000 buckets. This is grossly inefficient when bucket amounts are within the time complexities of *O(N^2)*, which makes buckets sort just as time costly (if not, worse) than the traditional comparison sorting algorithms. However, if the conditions are right, then Bucket Sort may be a good choice.